# Erlang, why does it not have global variables and records?

Tags: erlang

I am doing a lab now in Erlang and it's the first time I write Erlang ever. I have an initial_state function that is supposed to set the initial state for a client in a chat program. But what's the point of setting this initial state if you don't have anything to store it in like in Java or C? I mean it feels like I'm just creating the initial state and then just throwing it away. What'e the point of that? I want somewhere to store it so I can use it later.

initial_state(Nick, GUIName) ->
    #cl_st { gui = GUIName }.

Comment: Did you try to read any tutorials before asking such questions?

Comment: Pass the state to everything that needs it.  This is good to do in Java / C also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is lacking some context, it could be useful to have the whole module to give a good answer.

Anyway, the function you show is quite simple, it is a function that return a client state record with the field gui equal to GUIName.

This function looks strange because it has 2 parameters, and the parameter Nick is unused.

In erlang there are only local variables, they belong to one process and cannot be shared with another one. This implies 2 things:

- If you want to keep track of a variable value, the process to which it belong must not die, so it must be recursive.
- If you want exchange between processes you must use messages

It is usual to split a server into an init function, some callback and interface functions and an infinite loop. I guess that it is a good introduction to the gen_server behavior of OTP. I can imagine to complement your code that way:

```
%% the record state definition, it will include
%% the client nickname,
%% the gui name (or pid ?)
%% the client cart with a default value equals to the empty list
-record(cl_st,{nick,gui,cart=[]}).

initial_state(Nick, GUIName) -> 
%% the role of this function could be to start processes such as the gui
%% and return the initial state
    %% add some code to start the gui
    #cl_st { gui = GUIName, nick = Nick}.

%% an example of an interface function to add some item to the client cart
%% it simply pack the parameters into a tuple and send it to the server
%% Note that the server is identified by its pid, so somwhere there must be a unique
%% server that keep the list of all clients and their server pid
add_to_cart(Pid,Item,Price,Quantity) ->
    Pid ! {add_to_cart,Item,Price,Quantity}.

%% this function calls the init function, starts the server in a new process (usage of spawn) with the
%% initial state and returns the server pid 
start(Nick,GUIName) ->
    State = initial_state(Nick, GUIName),
    spawn(?MODULE,cl_loop,[State]).

stop(Pid) ->
    Pid ! stop.

%% the server loop
%% this example manages 2 kind of messages
cl_loop(State) ->
    receive
        %% add to cart simply builds a tuple made of item, price and quantity and add it to a list
        %% of tuple representing the cart content.
        %% it calls itself recursively with a new state as parameter where the old cart
        %% is replaced by the new one
        {add_to_cart,Item,Price,Quantity} ->
            NewCart = [{Item,Price,Quantity}|State#cl_st.cart],
            cl_loop(State#cl_st{cart=NewCart});
        %% to stop the server, it calls the terminate callback function and does not call itself recursively 
        stop ->
            terminate(State);
        %% other messages are ignored, the server simply calls itself with an unchanged state
        Ignored ->
            cl_loop(State)
    end. 

%% a callback function to terminate the server properly
terminate(State#cl_st{gui = GUIName, nick = Nick}) ->
    %% some code to stop the gui
    {stopped_client, Nick}.
```

*(it must have error in the code, I didn't even compile it)*